# Is there a dictionary which denotes if its words are concrete or abstract nouns?

Tags: dictionaries, abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

Is there a dictionary which denotes if its words are *concrete* or *abstract* nouns?

I found already a dictionary which denotes if the words are countable or uncountable (Merriam Webster learner's) but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, I don't think so because it should be implicit from the definition of the word whether it's abstract or concrete. Clearly, "book" and "paper are concrete because you can touch them whereas "traffic" and "spite" are abstract because you cannot touch them. I'm pretty sure that's the basis for being abstract or concrete with regard to nouns.

Comment: No, I don't think so either, but this link discusses 'grey' areas in identifying them, which might be useful: http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2012/01/abstract-and-concrete-nouns/